# Access 2010 Count Amount of Instances

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to add a column to my Access 2010 database that provides a version number based upon the value of another row. For example if I had a column that was:
A
A
B
A
C
B

I would like a calculated column that returns:
1
2
1
3
1
2

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases are unordered. In other words, there is no concept of which row "comes before" any other row. So you cannot set any value based on the order of entries.